# Elegant SVG shadow outline for visibility (without using filter)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, rect

I need to find a way to outline my transparent rectangle that has black stroke with some sort of shadow to make it visible on any color background

Here is my attempt to do that without filters (can't use them as it's causing too many reflows) using two rectangles - but it doesn't looks as close as nice as div with shadow.

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omMmRj
```

```
<svg id='mySvg' width="100mm" height="100mm">
   <rect id="mainRect" x="25mm" y="25mm" height="50mm" width="50mm" fill="none"></rect>
   <rect id="secondaryRect" x="25.5mm" y="25.5mm"  height="49mm" width="49mm" fill="none"></rect>
</svg>

body {
  background: white;
}
#hello{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}
```

And here is sample output I expect to be on that rectangle using div + shadow -> it highliths white border with black color so it's visible on any background. Need to find a way to do same on svg rect without filter.

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJBEKG
```

Comment: SVG doesn't have reflows so what does "too many reflows" actually mean?

Comment: Moving svg element that contains filter is very slow (I resize it and change viewBox in same time). Tried that and sadly, filter is causing it. Or probably one of it's properties.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your problem would be making the two rectangles the sane size and using stroke-dashoffset for one of the two rectangles:

```css
#mySvg{
  border:1px solid black;
  background:orange;
}
#mainRect{
  stroke : white;
  stroke-width: .5mm;
  stroke-dasharray : 3.5mm;
}
#secondaryRect{
  stroke : black;
  stroke-width: .5mm;
  stroke-dasharray : 3.5mm;
  stroke-dashoffset : 3.5mm;
}
```

```html
<svg id='mySvg' width="100mm" height="100mm">
  <rect id="mainRect" x="25mm" y="25mm" height="50mm" width="50mm" fill="none"></rect>
    <rect id="secondaryRect" x="25mm" y="25mm"  height="50mm" width="50mm" fill="none"></rect>
</svg>
```

An other solution would be using filters. Please observe that in this case I've added fill="orange" to your rectangle.

```css
#mySvg{
  border:1px solid black;
  background:orange;
}
#mainRect{
  stroke : white;
  stroke-width: .5mm;

}
```

```html
<svg id='mySvg' width="100mm" height="100mm">
  <filter id="outline">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
  <rect id="mainRect" x="25mm" y="25mm" height="50mm" width="50mm" fill="orange" filter="url(#outline)"></rect>   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - nice and good solution is to use secondary rectangle (that has to be put first as SVG layers last items on front), make it bit bigger than other rectangle so it outlines it nicely.

```css
body {
  background: green;
}
#hello{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}
#mainRect{
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.5mm;
    stroke-dasharray: 3mm;
}
#secondaryRect{
    stroke: #424242;
    stroke-width: 1mm;
    stroke-dasharray: 3mm;
}
```

```html
<svg id='mySvg' width="100mm" height="100mm">
   <rect id="secondaryRect" x="25mm" y="25mm"  height="50mm" width="50mm" fill="none"></rect>
   <rect id="mainRect" x="25mm" y="25mm" height="50mm" width="50mm" fill="none"></rect>
</svg>
```